# Mathematica and Desmos produce different plots

Tags: plotting

So I was trying to plot a function using Mathematica and desmos. While desmos is giving me the right output, Mathematica's output plot is not right. I can't figure out why.

**Equation:**

$$ \left(\frac{1}{g-1}-\ \frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{x}\right)x^{4\left(\frac{g-1}{g+1}\right)}-\frac{d\left(\frac{1}{g-1}\ +\ \frac{y}{2}\right)}{y^{\frac{g-1}{g+1}}}=0 $$

Desmos output :

[image: desmos output]

at g =1.2 and d = 0.9

Now mathematica :

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*
     x^(4*((g - 1)/(g + 1))) - ((d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)))/(g - 
        1)) - ((d*y^((2 - g)/(1 + g)))/2) == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 
   5}], {g, 1.20}, {d, 0.900}]
```

Output:

[image: mathematical output]

The lower curve is missing in the Mathematica plot. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug of Mathematica? A very powerful command of Maple `Digits := 30;
DirectSearch:-SolveEquations(eval((1/(g - 1) - 3/2 + 2/x)*x^(4*(g - 1)/(g + 1)) - d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1))/(g - 1) - d*y^((2 - g)/(g + 1))/2 = 0, {d = 9/10, g = 6/5}), {0 <= x, 0 <= y, x <= 2, y <= 2}, AllSolutions, solutions = 3, tolerances = 10^(-20));` find no solution there, resulting in `Vector[row](4, [0.0164649685031266763727994509932, Vector[column](1, [0.128315893415923642443134361579]), [x = 1.00000000000000402257485459537, y = 2.00000000000000000000000000000], 1559])`.

Comment: Also the command of Maple `plots:-implicitplot(eval((1/(g - 1) - 3/2 + 2/x)*x^(4*(g - 1)/(g + 1)) - d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1))/(g - 1) - d*y^((2 - g)/(g + 1))/2 = 0, {d = 9/10, g = 6/5}), x = 0 .. 2, y = 0 .. 2, gridrefine = 5, thickness = 4)` produces the vertical segment between $(0,0)$ and $(0,2)$, not something close to the x-axis..

Comment: `FindRoot[((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*
    x^(4*((g - 1)/(g + 1))) - ((d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)))/(g - 1)) - ((d*
       y^((2 - g)/(1 + g)))/2) /. {d -> 9/10, g -> 6/5, x -> 1}, {y, 
  0}]` results in `{y -> 2.4308}`.

Comment: The command `d = 9/10; g = 
 6/5; x = 1; NSolve[((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*
     x^(4*((g - 1)/(g + 1))) - ((d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)))/(g - 
        1)) - ((d*y^((2 - g)/(1 + g)))/2) == 0 && y >= -1 && y <= 2,
  y]` results in `{}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something wrong with your equation inside `ContourPlot`!

Try

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*x^(4 (g - 1)/(g + 1))   - 
d/y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)) (1/(g - 1) + y/2)  == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5,5}], {g, 1.20}, {d, 0.900}]
```

[image]

Image now shows the two branches!

Comment: Did you try to verify that result near the x-axis?

Comment: -1. The command `d = 9/10; g = 
 6/5; x = 1; NSolve[((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*
     x^(4*((g - 1)/(g + 1))) - ((d*y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)))/(g - 
        1)) - ((d*y^((2 - g)/(1 + g)))/2) == 0 && y >= -1 && y <= 2,
  y]` results in `{}`.

Comment: As I mentioned OP (and you too) took the wrong equation. That's all.

Comment: You are right. `d = 9/10; g = 
 6/5; x = 1; NSolve[(((1/(g - 1)) - 3/2 + 2/x)*x^(4 (g - 1)/(g + 1)) -
      d/y^((g - 1)/(g + 1)) (1/(g - 1) + y/2)) == 0 && y >= -1 && 
  y <= 2, y]` performs `{{y -> 0.126267}}`.

Comment: I changed my mind concerning -1.